# vb.net - Can i add the content of a txt to my program?

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if there is a method to "finish" a program from a txt for example if i have a script like this :

```
Private Sub ButtonNum_Click(Index As Integer)    
    If Num_of_digit > 0 Then    
        If Num_of_digit < 30 Then    
             panel. Caption = panel.Caption + Right$(Str(Index), 1)
        Num_of_digit = Num_of_digit + 1
        End If
    Else
        panel.Caption = Right$(Str(Index), 1)
        Num_of_digit = 1
    End If
    CheckValue

End Sub
```

And i want that a part of code will not be in my exe but in a .txt what can i do?Is there any way i can do that?

Comment: You can make command line for not executable coding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the txt file and get it into a string in your app.  Either use a Stream Reader or File.ReadAllText like `Dim value As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\file.txt")`